# TypeError: d is undefined error in summernote text editor

Tags: javascript

I am  integrating summernote text editor in my project, when browse for insert image i am getting TypeError: d is undefined error. I have attached screen shot. please help.

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggwJt.png
```

following is my code.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cause_desc').summernote({
        height: 300, // set editor height
        minHeight: 150, // set minimum height of editor
        maxHeight: 350, // set maximum height of editor
        placeholder: 'Write here...',
    });
});
</script>
```

When i will click on insert image button i am getting above error.

Comment: It doesn't give any information to figure out the issue. Please provide more info.

Comment: can you add complete snippet here!

Comment: ok  im attaching full screen shot.

Comment: Do you have `#cause_desc` in DOM?

Comment: yes   <textarea name="cause_desc" id="cause_desc" cols="" rows="" class="form-control"></textarea>